# Serilog always stuck at when app starting

Tags: c#, .net-core, serilog

I implement the Serilog into my AspNetCore 3.1 Web API. My first idea is logging to Mssql. But when i write the code into right place, application does not start.

My Startup file is:

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.Seq("http://localhost:5341").CreateLogger();

            try
            {
                Log.Information("Host starting...");

                Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg =>
                {
                    Debug.Print(msg);
                    Debugger.Break();
                });

                CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Fatal(ex, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
            }
            finally
            {
                Log.CloseAndFlush();
            }

        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseSerilog()
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

And after hit the F5 button, debug console has stuck at this line:

```
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/3.1.4/System.Runtime.Numerics.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
```

Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: You aren't setting up any logger configuration inside of `UseSerilog`. You might wanna start there.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 which configuration? I'm already configurate when create Log object. Am I wrong?

Comment: Try this: `UseSerilog((ctx, log) => log.WriteTo.Seq("url"))`. By default it will override the global Logger as well

Comment: Removed Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.Seq("http://localhost:5341").CreateLogger(); and use your comment. but no work... why, why dont starting? i'm gonna crazy...

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue when using Serilog. It appears that the UseSerilog() statement needs more information passed through it.  [The docs provide an example of this.](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore/blob/dev/samples/Sample/Program.cs) I was able to get my program running by using

```
.UseSerilog((context, services, configuration) => configuration
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration)
    .ReadFrom.Services(services)
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .WriteTo.Console())
```

Comment: Thank you, this resolved an issue I was having.